# Effectively using try() to delete a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dropbox-api

I'm writing a script for a rails app that manages (in a loose sense of the term) files in Dropbox through the `dropbox-api` gem. Anyway, I'm attempting to delete a file (if it exists) before taking a set of actions.

To delete the file I use the following:

```
Dropbox::API::Client#destroy

Removes the file specified by path

Returns a Dropbox::API::File object of the deleted file

client.destroy 'file.txt' # => #<Dropbox::API::File>
```

Where client is

```
client = Dropbox::API::Client.new(:token  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx', :secret => 'yyyyyyyyyyy')
```

Simply deleting the file is not a problem; it's that I'd like the script not to throw an error if the file doesn't exist.  I thought that this might be a job for `try()` but I haven't been able to get it to work.  Is `try()` appropriate for this application?  If not, might there be a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the code in begin and rescue block. Like this:

```
begin
 #code here which may throw error
rescue
 #code here to rescue if it throws error
 puts "File not found"
end
```

This is an example. You can do like this. Hope this helps.

Edit:

The `try` method is used when you need to rescue any exception while calling any object's attributes. May be I am not clear with this sentence, I will explain with an example. Suppose there are `users` you are not sure about their attributes. So what you can do is:

```
@user.try(:name)
```

So if the name exists then it would return the value or else if it doesn't exists it will not throw and error instead it will return `nil`.

The `begin` `rescue` block is useful when you want to handle any exception. Like the above your code might throw an error but you need to handle the error, it should not break the functionality, so you use it. Hope I am clear with this.

Comment: Thanks for the response; it worked well!  Is there a quick explanation you could give of when it's appropriate to use `begin`-`rescue` and when it's appropriate to use `try()`?  I feel like this is rather fundamental misunderstanding that I'm having.

Comment: I have added details in the answer